# Error in Flutter app: Parameter 'key' and 'title' can't have a value of 'null'

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-maps

I'm encountering the following errors in my Flutter app:

```
lib/main.dart:34:19: Error: The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Key', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
lib/main.dart:34:29: Error: The parameter 'title' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
lib/main.dart:54:53: Error: A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.
lib/main.dart:40:23: Error: Field '_controller' should be initialized because its type 'GoogleMapController' doesn't allow null.
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
```

I have a main.dart file with the code provided, which is intended to fetch location coordinates from Firebase and display them as markers on a map. The sending part is working correctly, but I'm getting these errors when running the app.

Any help in resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'api_keys.dart';
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: apiKey,
      authDomain: 'your_auth_domain',
      databaseURL: 'your_database_url',
      projectId: 'your_project_id',
      storageBucket: 'your_storage_bucket',
      messagingSenderId: 'your_messaging_sender_id',
      appId: 'your_app_id',
    ),
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GoogleMapController _controller;
  Set<Marker> _markers = {};
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    _controller = controller;
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getMarkers();
  }
  void _getMarkers() async {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
    DatabaseReference ref = database.reference().child('locations');
    ref.onValue.listen((event) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = event.snapshot.value;
      if (values != null) {
        values.forEach((k, v) {
          double lat = v['lat'];
          double lng = v['lng'];
          String title = v['title'];
          Marker marker = Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId(k.toString()),
            position: LatLng(lat, lng),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: title),
          );
          setState(() {
            _markers.add(marker);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GoogleMap(
        markers: _markers,
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
          zoom: 11.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

​

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a sample of the array that you're feeding to your code from firebase?